# Can't use Django in virtualenv

Tags: python, django, virtualenv

I have two Django projects and I created two different virtualenv for them.
When I create another one virtualenv and install Django and create a django project I tried `python manage.py` runserver and have this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 8, in <module>
    from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
ImportError: No module named 'django'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 14, in <module>
    import django
ImportError: No module named 'django'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 17, in <module>
    "Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and "
ImportError: Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable? Did you forget to activate a virtual environment?
```

What I need to do?
I already tried uninstalling Django, pip, virtualenv and re-install:

```
sudo apt-get install python3-pip
sudo pip3 install virtualenv
sudo virtualenv ENV
source newenv/bin/activate
sudo -H pip3 install django
```

Comment: When you are in an active virtual env, you just run `pip install...` no `sudo`, no `pip3`.

Comment: then i get:Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/morilon/dj/ENV/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 215, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/home/morilon/dj/ENV/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 342, in run
    prefix=options.prefix_path,
  File "/home/morilon/dj/ENV/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 784, in install
    **kwargs
  File "/home/morilon/dj/ENV/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/req/req_install.py", line 851, i

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `sudo` with virtualenvs can cause a lot of scope issues, as well as a virture of virtualenvs is that you shouldn't need root permissions for them (in most cases).

Also if you have virtaulenv installed for python 2 as well, it might be defaulting to that one.

```
sudo apt-get install python3-pip
sudo pip3 install virtualenv

# I prefer using this over `virtualenv --python=/usr/bin/python3 ENV`
python3 -m venv ENV 
source ENV/bin/activate

# Can do a `which pip3` here to make sure it's using the ENV one
pip3 install django

# Could also do full path of `ENV/bin/pip3 install django`
```

Comment: Glad to hear @Dorian, would appreciate the answer being accepted if you don't have further issues, Thanks!